# Sql query Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s) in rails

Tags: sql, mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

SELECT * 
    FROM   `jobs` 
    WHERE  (SELECT DISTINCT jobs.* 
            FROM   jobs, job_requests 
            WHERE (jobs.user_id = 1) OR 
                  (job_requests.user_id = 1 AND job_requests.job_id =   jobs.id)
           )

This sql gives me:

```
Mysql::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s).
```

If I execute the select from the where clause it works

```
SELECT DISTINCT jobs.* FROM jobs, job_requests 
WHERE  (jobs.user_id = 1) OR 
       (job_requests.user_id = 1 AND job_requests.job_id = jobs.id)
```

Could somebody explain me why? This query is generated by rails activerecord so the main select is needed.

The ror code:

```
has_many :my_jobs, :class_name=>"Job", :finder_sql =>
    'SELECT DISTINCT jobs.* ' +
    'FROM jobs, job_requests ' +
    'WHERE (jobs.user_id = #{id}) OR ' +
    '(job_requests.user_id = #{id} AND job_requests.job_id = jobs.id AND job_requests.request_status IN ("requested", "confirmed") )'
```

Comment: Can you show RoR code that generates such query?

Comment: Yes, i added the ror code too. Basically i want to retrieve the jobs where the user is the owner and the jobs where he is applied( has jobs through job_requests) but i want them together for further filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am submitting my answer based on the additional information provided. The query below should address your requirement.

```
Job.all(:conditions=> [ " 
 jobs.user_id = ? OR 
 EXISTS (
   SELECT * 
   FROM   job_requests AS B
   WHERE  B.job_id = jobs.id AND B.user_id = ?
 )", user_id, user_id ]
)
```

If you want an efficient version of the same query then you should go with UNIONs.

```
sql = "
  SELECT * 
  FROM   jobs A WHERE A.user_id = ?
 UNION
  SELECT * 
  FROM   jobs A, job_requests B 
  WHERE  A.id = B.job_id AND B.user_id = ?
 "    
Job.find_by_sql(Job.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [sql, user_id, user_id]))
```

The first query can be converted to a `named_scope`.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  named_scope :for_user, lambda { |user_id| { :conditions=> [ " 
     jobs.user_id = ? OR 
     EXISTS (
       SELECT * 
       FROM   job_requests AS B
       WHERE  B.job_id = jobs.id AND B.user_id = ?
     )", user_id, user_id ] }
  }
end
```

Now you can use the named_scope as follows:

```
Jobs.for_user(current_user)
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but my only problem is that i want to further filter the results set with names scopes. Could be applied named scopes here?

Answer (score 1):

SQL query: Documentation

```
SELECT (
'95.86.122.224', NOW( ) , '95.86.122.224', '95.86.122.224'
)
FROM orders
LEFT JOIN visitors ON visitors.ip = '95.86.122.224'
WHERE visitors.ip IS NULL
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

MySQL said: Documentation

```
#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you correctly you need to restructure as

```
SELECT * FROM jobs 
 WHERE EXISTS 
       (SELECT DISTINCT jobs.* 
          FROM jobs, job_requests 
         WHERE (jobs.user_id = 1) 
            OR (job_requests.user_id = 1 AND job_requests.job_id = jobs.id))
```

I'm guessing you only want to select from jobs where the inner query is true, the above will do this for you.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution which could be integrated in ror too.

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work, if you want to get the `jobs` with `job requests` for a given `user`:

```
Job.all( :joins      => :jobs_requests, 
         :conditions => ["job_requests.user_id = ?", user_id])
```

Comment: Something like this, but the problem is that in this case i wont give back jobs where the user id doesn't match. The criteria is: or the user is owner of the job(jobs.user_id = user_id), or he is applied for a job through job request(job_request.user_id = user_id AND job_request.job_id = jobs.id). Hope this make sense.

Comment: I have added another answer for your question. It should cover your scenario